# facebook sdk login nativecrypto error

Tags: android, facebook, ssl, facebook-login

I am using Facebook SDK to allow the user to login with the Facebook SSO button in my app. It works fine on all android devices (above sdk 7) except for one. Bedove HY5001, running android version 4.2.1.

When the user clicks on the Facebook SSO login button, Facebook authentication occurs (the Facebook app is started and works it's magic as intended) and then the attached logcat error occurs and returns to the activity, where the user is still not-logged in.

Any idea why this could happen to this specific user? Other Android apps using facebook login work fine.

Below is the code of the login activity:

```js
 public class Loco extends FragmentActivity {

private String email, at;
private LoginButton loginBtn;
public Loco parent;
public Context context;
public String result;

private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("email","publish_actions");

public boolean loggedin, registered, error;

SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    loggedin = false;
    parent = this;
    context = this;

    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, statusCallback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    loginBtn = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fbLogin);
    loginBtn.setBackgroundColor(0xFF375796);
    loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                loginBtn.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new UserInfoChangedCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
                        if (user != null) {

                            requestPermissions();
                            email = user.asMap().get("email").toString();

                            Intent intent = new Intent(parent, xxx.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            parent.finish();
                        } 
                    }
                });

        }

    });

}



private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {

            Log.d("FacebookSampleActivity", "Facebook session opened");

        } else if (state.isClosed()) {

            Log.d("FacebookSampleActivity", "Facebook session closed");
        }
    }
};

public boolean checkPermissions() {
    Session s = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (s != null) {
        return s.getPermissions().contains("email");
    } else
        return false;
}

public void requestPermissions() {
    Session s = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (s != null){
        s.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS));
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session.isOpened()) {
        at = session.getAccessToken();
        System.out.print(at + " Access Token inside onResume");
    } else {
        at = "invalid";
    }

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    System.out.println("onactivityRes");
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
}
```

}

And the logcat output is:

```
  11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Returned from SSL_Read() with result 1, error code 0 ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): ssl=0x5e7d97c8 sslRead buf=0x41e86e88 len=1,timeo=0
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Doing SSL_Read() ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Returned from SSL_Read() with result 1, error code 0 ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): ssl=0x5e7d97c8 sslRead buf=0x41e86ec0 len=1,timeo=0
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Doing SSL_Read() ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Returned from SSL_Read() with result 1, error code 0 ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): ssl=0x5e7d97c8 sslRead buf=0x41e86ef8 len=1,timeo=0
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Doing SSL_Read() ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Returned from SSL_Read() with result 1, error code 0 ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): ssl=0x5e7d97c8 sslRead buf=0x41e86f30 len=1,timeo=0
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Doing SSL_Read() ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Returned from SSL_Read() with result 1, error code 0 ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): ssl=0x5e7d97c8 sslRead buf=0x41e86f68 len=1,timeo=0
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Doing SSL_Read() ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Returned from SSL_Read() with result 1, error code 0 ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): ssl=0x5e7d97c8 sslRead buf=0x41e86fa0 len=1,timeo=0
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Doing SSL_Read() ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Returned from SSL_Read() with result 1, error code 0 ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): ssl=0x5e7d97c8 sslRead buf=0x41e86fd8 len=1,timeo=0
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Doing SSL_Read() ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Returned from SSL_Read() with result 1, error code 0 ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): ssl=0x5e7d97c8 sslRead buf=0x41e87010 len=1,timeo=0
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Doing SSL_Read() ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Returned from SSL_Read() with result 1, error code 0 ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): ssl=0x5e7d97c8 sslRead buf=0x41e87048 len=1,timeo=0
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Doing SSL_Read() ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Returned from SSL_Read() with result 1, error code 0 ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): ssl=0x5e7d97c8 sslRead buf=0x41e87080 len=1,timeo=0
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Doing SSL_Read() ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Returned from SSL_Read() with result 1, error code 0 ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): ssl=0x5e7d97c8 sslRead buf=0x41e870b8 len=1,timeo=0
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Doing SSL_Read() ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Returned from SSL_Read() with result 1, error code 0 ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): ssl=0x5e7d97c8 sslRead buf=0x41e870f0 len=1,timeo=0
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Doing SSL_Read() ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Returned from SSL_Read() with result 1, error code 0 ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): ssl=0x5e7d97c8 sslRead buf=0x41e87128 len=1,timeo=0
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Doing SSL_Read() ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Returned from SSL_Read() with result 1, error code 0 ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): ssl=0x5e7d97c8 sslRead buf=0x41e87160 len=1,timeo=0
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Doing SSL_Read() ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Returned from SSL_Read() with result 1, error code 0 ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): ssl=0x5e7d97c8 sslRead buf=0x41e87198 len=1,timeo=0
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Doing SSL_Read() ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Returned from SSL_Read() with result 1, error code 0 ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): ssl=0x5e7d97c8 sslRead buf=0x41e871d0 len=1,timeo=0
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Doing SSL_Read() ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Returned from SSL_Read() with result 1, error code 0 ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): ssl=0x5e7d97c8 sslRead buf=0x41e87208 len=1,timeo=0
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Doing SSL_Read() ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Returned from SSL_Read() with result 1, error code 0 ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): ssl=0x5e7d97c8 sslRead buf=0x41e87240 len=1,timeo=0
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Doing SSL_Read() ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Returned from SSL_Read() with result 1, error code 0 ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): ssl=0x5e7d97c8 sslRead buf=0x41e87408 len=1,timeo=0
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Doing SSL_Read() ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Returned from SSL_Read() with result 1, error code 0 ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.646: D/NativeCrypto(11422): ssl=0x5e7d97c8 sslRead buf=0x41e87440 len=1,timeo=0
11-08 19:13:27.647: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Doing SSL_Read() ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.647: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Returned from SSL_Read() with result 1, error code 0 ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.654: D/NativeCrypto(11422): ssl=0x5e7d97c8 sslRead buf=0x41e8b5c8 len=650,timeo=0
11-08 19:13:27.654: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Doing SSL_Read() ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:27.654: D/NativeCrypto(11422): Returned from SSL_Read() with result 650, error code 0 ssl=0x5e7d97c8, appData=0x5ebec740
11-08 19:13:31.451: V/Provider/Settings(11422): invalidate [system]: current 567 != cached 0
11-08 19:13:31.456: V/Provider/Settings(11422): from db cache, name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0
11-08 19:13:31.465: V/Provider/Settings(11422): invalidate [secure]: current 1 != cached 0
11-08 19:13:31.466: V/Provider/Settings(11422): from db cache, name = android_id , value = c8d6fdc530ca508c
11-08 19:13:31.468: D/dalvikvm(11422): create interp thread : stack size=32KB
11-08 19:13:31.469: D/dalvikvm(11422): create new thread
11-08 19:13:31.469: D/dalvikvm(11422): new thread created
11-08 19:13:31.469: D/dalvikvm(11422): update thread list
11-08 19:13:31.469: D/dalvikvm(11422): threadid=13: interp stack at 0x5dda2000
11-08 19:13:31.469: D/dalvikvm(11422): threadid=13: created from interp
11-08 19:13:31.469: D/dalvikvm(11422): start new thread
11-08 19:13:31.469: D/dalvikvm(11422): create interp thread : stack size=32KB
11-08 19:13:31.469: D/dalvikvm(11422): create new thread
11-08 19:13:31.469: D/dalvikvm(11422): new thread created
11-08 19:13:31.469: D/dalvikvm(11422): update thread list
11-08 19:13:31.469: D/dalvikvm(11422): threadid=13: notify debugger
11-08 19:13:31.469: D/dalvikvm(11422): threadid=13 (Timer-0): calling run()
11-08 19:13:31.470: D/dalvikvm(11422): threadid=14: interp stack at 0x5deaa000
11-08 19:13:31.470: D/dalvikvm(11422): threadid=14: created from interp
11-08 19:13:31.470: D/dalvikvm(11422): start new thread
11-08 19:13:31.470: D/dalvikvm(11422): threadid=14: notify debugger
11-08 19:13:31.470: D/dalvikvm(11422): threadid=14 (Timer-1): calling run()
11-08 19:13:31.472: D/dalvikvm(11422): create interp thread : stack size=32KB
11-08 19:13:31.472: D/dalvikvm(11422): create new thread
11-08 19:13:31.472: D/dalvikvm(11422): new thread created
11-08 19:13:31.472: D/dalvikvm(11422): update thread list
11-08 19:13:31.472: D/dalvikvm(11422): threadid=15: interp stack at 0x5dfb2000
11-08 19:13:31.472: D/dalvikvm(11422): threadid=15: created from interp
11-08 19:13:31.472: D/dalvikvm(11422): start new thread
11-08 19:13:31.473: D/dalvikvm(11422): threadid=15: notify debugger
11-08 19:13:31.473: D/dalvikvm(11422): threadid=15 (SharedPreferencesImpl-load): calling run()
11-08 19:13:31.473: D/dalvikvm(11422): threadid=15: exiting
11-08 19:13:31.473: D/dalvikvm(11422): threadid=15: bye!
11-08 19:13:31.694: D/skia(11422): Flag is not 10
11-08 19:13:31.741: I/SurfaceTextureClient(11422): [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5e8108c0) fps:0.10, dur:9748.44, max:9748.44, min:9748.44
11-08 19:13:31.741: I/SurfaceTextureClient(11422): [STC::queueBuffer] this:0x5e8108c0, api:1, last queue time elapsed:9748.44
11-08 19:13:31.806: V/InputMethodManager(11422): onWindowFocus: null softInputMode=289 first=true flags=#1810100
11-08 19:13:31.806: V/InputMethodManager(11422): START INPUT: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41ed4ec0 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-720,1280} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@41ef4e18 controlFlags=#104
11-08 19:13:31.819: V/InputMethodManager(11422): Starting input: Bind result=InputBindResult{com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy@41ef5778 com.syntellia.fleksy.kb/com.syntellia.fleksy.keyboard.Fleksy #1002}
11-08 19:13:31.858: D/OpenGLRenderer(11422): Flushing caches (mode 0)
11-08 19:13:32.689: D/IPCThreadState(11422): [DN #5] BR_CLEAR_DEATH_NOTIFICATION_DONE cookie 0x5cc6b3b0
11-08 19:13:32.705: D/OpenGLRenderer(11422): Flushing caches (mode 1)
11-08 19:13:33.461: D/OpenGLRenderer(11422): Flushing caches (mode 0)
11-08 19:13:34.323: I/System.out(11422): onactivityRes
11-08 19:13:34.351: V/InputMethodManager(11422): onWindowFocus: null softInputMode=33 first=true flags=#1810100
11-08 19:13:34.352: V/InputMethodManager(11422): START INPUT: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41644ef0 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-720,1280} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@41f4dca0 controlFlags=#104
11-08 19:13:34.353: V/InputMethodManager(11422): Starting input: Bind result=InputBindResult{com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy@41f4e540 com.syntellia.fleksy.kb/com.syntellia.fleksy.keyboard.Fleksy #1003}
11-08 19:13:34.472: D/FacebookSampleActivity(11422): Facebook session closed
11-08 19:13:34.516: D/OpenGLRenderer(11422): Flushing caches (mode 0)
```

Comment: Same problem here, causes all important logs to disappear due to its massive log entries

Comment: Are you facing this problem under specific circumstances (like i describe in the original post) or is it a generic problem for you?

Comment: I can login successfully but after that it prints these logs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it some time ago and I thought I would share the answer to help others. To be honest I don't know why the code below worked on all devices while the code in my original post didn't work on that one device (Bedove HY5001). I hope someone can explain that.

Ps. Apologies for the terrible code formatting below.

```
  public LoginButton loginButton; //FB SSO button

    loginButton.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
        LoginScreen.this.user = user;
    }

 });
loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(Configurations.fbReqPublicProfile,Configurations.fbReqEmail));
  // session state call back event
loginButton.setSessionStatusCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {

   @Override
   public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

    if (session.isOpened()) {
            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                          @Override
                          public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,Response response) {
                              //Do your stuff here e.g as follows:
                             String facebook_email = user.asMap().get("email").toString();
                          }
                      });
          }

   }
  });
```